# WordPress' ACF plugin: break at instructions field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

When you create a field in the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin in WordPress, you can add an instruction to the field. Is there a way to add an break to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - the ACF *Instructions* setting accepts some basic HTML.

A line break can be added using `<br />`.

Answer (score 1):

Well put @Tim Malone. I'm sharing an example for a description in one of my custom fields.

```html
Wrap a word in a span tag to highlight:<br/><br/>
<code>&lt;span&gt;<span style="background-color: #ffffcc;">highlight</span>&lt;/span&gt;</code>
<br/><br/>
```